# Create intent with excluded MIME type?

Tags: android

Is it currently possible to exclude a type from the Intent type?

E.g. Having an intent that acceps all images, except PNG images. Something like this:

```
 action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
 type = "*/*"
 putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "!image/png"))
 putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
```

But `!image/png` doesn't work and keeps returning PNGs.

Comment: I don't think that there is support for this, sorry.

Comment: This isn't possible right now, sadly.

Comment: The only thing you could do is after you got the URI, get the type and check if it is a png file. If it is, then block it.